# LocalStack Create S3 Bucket locally with terraform doesn't have a name

Tags: amazon-s3, localstack

Aloha,

**TL&DR:**

I am trying to create an s3 bucket locally by using terraform instead of awscli or awslocal and i am running in some errors. I am wondering if this way is even supported by localstack. I am not sure what i did wrong here but i guess i need to use the awscli here to create s3 buckets. *Anyone has an idea why the bucket name is not forwarded?*

**Long Version:**

I am using a docker-compose.yaml to define the localstack docker container:

```
version: '3'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:0.10.5
    ports:
    - "4572:4572"
    - "4584:4584"
    - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
    - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
    - SERVICES=s3,secretsmanager
    - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
    - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
    - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
    - DOCKER_HOST=${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_HOST-unix:///var/run/docker.sock}
    - TF_VAR_localstack_host=localhost
    volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

I use this terraform main.tf to define what i want to create in the docker container:

```
variable "localstack_host" {
  default = "localhost"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.39.0"
  alias = "local"
  region = "eu-central-1"
  access_key = "This is not an actual access key."
  secret_key = "This is not an actual secret key."
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true
  endpoints {
    secretsmanager  = "http://${var.localstack_host}:4584"
    s3              = "http://${var.localstack_host}:4572"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_encryption_test_bucket" {
  bucket = "s3-encryption-test-bucket"
  provider = "aws.local"
}
```

After running the docker container I then apply the terraform file to the local running instance of localstack:

```
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

The error i get from terraform is:

```
aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: Creating...
  acceleration_status:         "" => "<computed>"
  acl:                         "" => "private"
  arn:                         "" => "<computed>"
  bucket:                      "" => "s3-encryption-test-bucket"
  bucket_domain_name:          "" => "<computed>"
  bucket_regional_domain_name: "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy:               "" => "false"
  hosted_zone_id:              "" => "<computed>"
  region:                      "" => "<computed>"
  request_payer:               "" => "<computed>"
  versioning.#:                "" => "<computed>"
  website_domain:              "" => "<computed>"
  website_endpoint:            "" => "<computed>"
aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: Still creating... (20s elapsed)
.....
aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: Still creating... (2m10s elapsed)
aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: Still creating... (2m20s elapsed)

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket.s3_encryption_test_bucket: error getting S3 Bucket CORS configuration: timeout while waiting for state to become 'success' (timeout: 2m0s)
```

I also looked into the logs of the container and got this error message:

```
2019-12-12T13:24:45:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 240, in forward
    path=path, data=data, headers=forward_headers).......
```

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same problem, the solution for me was adding `s3_force_path_style = true` to `provider "aws"` section:

```
provider "aws" {
  ...
  s3_force_path_style = true
  ...
}
```

Comment: `s3_force_path_style` is now deprecated. It's been replaced by `s3_use_path_style`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Simply defining ACL in resource block solved it for me:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_encryption_test_bucket" {
  bucket = "s3-encryption-test-bucket"
  provider = "aws.local"
  acl = "private"
}
```